# Create infinite loop in Unity with delay

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to create a infinite loop in Unity without using the main thread? I saw some example, but it's not usefull:

```
while(true){
         var aa;
         debug.log("print.");
}
```

I want to add some delay like e.g. 2 seconds. If anybody knows the solution please help.

Comment: Coroutines are way to go :)

Comment: The best thing for you to use is probably coroutines.. with WaitForSeconds(2). Remembering that the Unity game engine already does a loop.

Comment: If you only want to make some simple operation then coroutines are okay. But i you would like to execute some heavy operation eg. Read large binary/text file ( 100+mb  ) then coroutines will fail ( in most cases )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this to create the loop;

```
private IEnumerator LoopFunction(float waitTime)
{
    while (true)
    {
        Debug.Log("print.");
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        //Second Log show passed waitTime (waitTime is float type value ) 
        Debug.Log("print1.");
    }
}
```

For calling the function, don't use `Update()` or `FixedUpdate()`, use something like `Start()` so you don't create infinite instances of the loop;

```
 void Start()
 {
      StartCoroutine(LoopFunction(1));
 }
```

Answer (score 11):

First define a [*Coroutines*](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html):

```
private IEnumerator InfiniteLoop()
{
    WaitForSeconds waitTime = new WaitForSeconds(2);
    while (true)
    {
        //var aa;
        Debug.Log("print.");
        yield return waitTime;
    }
}
```

Then call it like that:

```
 StartCoroutine(InfiniteLoop());
```

---

### Added note:

If you happen to change `Time.timeScale` and don't want that to affect delay time, use:

```
yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(2);
```

Comment: This kind of Coroutine is not healthy for any application. It will drive GC crazy. as you are creating a `YieldInstruction` every iteration. Would be better if you create an instance of WaitForSecond before while loop.

Comment: Invoke is better, where is @JoeBlow when you need him?

Comment: @UmairM I just followed the Unity documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html There is always some way to optimize this code if you feel that performances are an issue

Comment: @Ludovic Yes. Apparently Unity docs are not using while statement in that example. Performance is a big issue with coroutines, specially when they contain infinite loop. Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUYN8XtuUFA) which explains it better.

Comment: @UmairM My bad, in this page of the documentation it does not use  while statement but in the [StartCoroutine page](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) it does

Comment: @UmairM Interesting video by the way :)

Comment: @UmairM Check the fixed answer. `WaitForSeconds` should be declared outside the while loop and GC problems will be gone.

Comment: I think `InvokeRepeating` is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use coroutines..

```
//Call in your Method
StartCoroutine(LateStart(2.0f));
```

Then write coroutine like..

```
private IEnumerator LateStart(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    //After waitTime, you can use InvokeRepeating() for infinite loop infinite loop or you use a while(true) loop here
    InvokeRepeating("YourRepeatingMethod", 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
```

Here is the documentation for InvokeRepeating():
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Comment: Why coroutine? In the documentation, it just call InvokeRepeating. That's all.